# Is there a way to see "Unanswered: My Tags" like the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions

The iOS StackExchange app can show "Unanswered: My Tags" which only shows questions with no accepted answers, and that have one or more of my tags. Is there a preset (not [manually crafted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/view-or-search-for-unanswered-questions-with-a-certain-tag)) link/url like this on the desktop site?

If not, could it not be added as a feature to be like the iOS app?

Comment: Yes, If you have the [New Navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) enabled, you can go to the "Needs answer" tab > Filter: "Favorite Tags", show: "No answer". Which will take you to a url like: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&show=noanswer&page=1&pageSize=30&tagFilter=favorite. I'm not sure if this is doable with the old UI, maybe it is. You can use search with all your tags, that will work for sure.

Comment: Splendid. I'm still in queue to participate in testing.