# Why is Unanswered(My Tags) questions on the iOS app different than Unanswered(My Tags) questions on the web site?

Tags: support, mobile-web, ios-app

The list of questions I get on the iOS app for Unanswered(My Tags) questions is different than the web site's list of Unanswered(My Tags) questions, with the list of questions on the iOS app being more useful to me, so much that I would like to be able to use that list on the web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is how they are sorted.  On the web, these questions are sorted from highest to lowest score but on the app they are sorted from newest to oldest.

It looks like [the app followed the same sort order as the sites prior to 1.2.0.169](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244449/alternate-sorting-schemes-for-my-tags-in-mobile-app) when Arie made a the change.  I can't find any rationale for the vote ordering on the web though.

That said, it looks like that page will be supplanted by the new nav and there are [instructions in these comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295729/is-there-a-way-to-see-unanswered-my-tags-like-the-ios-app) on how to create a similar page (though I can't seem to follow them successfully).